# How to get only one image from Set() in Pony ORM

Tags: python, ponyorm

**Entities:**

```
class Car(db.Entity):
    image = Set("Image")
    name = Required(str, 40,)

class Image(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str, unique=True)
    car = Required(Car)
```

And I want to get information on cars-list page: one car - one image of that car.

I use:

```
cars = select((car, car.image) for car in Car).distinct().show()
```

I have

```
Car[1]|Image[1]  
Car[1]|Image[2]  
...
Car[5]Image[1]
Car[5]Image[2]
...
```

But I need only first image of each car, not all images.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to use plural name for `Set` attributes: `images = Set("Image")`. This way many queries look more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code to get only first image for each car (image with lowest id):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pony.orm import *

db = Database()
db.bind('sqlite', ':memory:', create_db=True)


class Car(db.Entity):
    image = Set("Image", lazy=True)
    name = Required(str, 40)

class Image(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str, unique=True)
    car = Required(Car)    

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

sql_debug(True)

with db_session:
    car1 = Car(name='car1')
    car2 = Car(name='car2')
    image1 = Image(name='image1', car = car1)
    image2 = Image(name='image2', car = car1)
    image3 = Image(name='image3', car = car2)
    cars = select((car, car.name, image, image.name) for car in Car for image in car.image if image.id == min(car.image.id)).show()
```

Result:

```
GET CONNECTION FROM THE LOCAL POOL
SWITCH TO AUTOCOMMIT MODE
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO "Car" ("name") VALUES (?)
[u'car1']

INSERT INTO "Car" ("name") VALUES (?)
[u'car2']

INSERT INTO "Image" ("name", "car") VALUES (?, ?)
[u'image1', 1]

INSERT INTO "Image" ("name", "car") VALUES (?, ?)
[u'image2', 1]

INSERT INTO "Image" ("name", "car") VALUES (?, ?)
[u'image3', 2]

SELECT "car"."id", "car"."name", "image"."id", "image"."name"
FROM "Car" "car"
  LEFT JOIN "Image" "image-1"
    ON "car"."id" = "image-1"."car"
  LEFT JOIN "Image" "image"
    ON "car"."id" = "image"."car"
GROUP BY "car"."id", "car"."name", "image"."id", "image"."name"
HAVING "image"."id" = MIN("image-1"."id")

car   |car.name|image   |image.name
------+--------+--------+----------
Car[1]|car1    |Image[1]|image1    
Car[2]|car2    |Image[3]|image3    
COMMIT
RELEASE CONNECTION
```

By the way, the generated sql is rather strange, I don't think that executing two identical left joins makes any sense.
Edit: OK, it makes sense (see comments).

Comment: Hi, I confirm that this answer is correct. The reason why query uses two left join is the following: in SQL there are no simple way to apply aggregated function such as `min` to the query and at the same time get values of other non-aggregated columns from the same query. Because of this, it is necessary to use two different joins, or calculate `min` value in a separate subquery.

Comment: Also I want to notice that if a single car instance is already loaded, you can get a single image of this car using `car.images.select().first()` (assuming that the collection name is 'images')

Comment: While executing the example in python 3.5 the result is "OperationalError: ambiguous column name: image.id". How does this happen?